# While rotating in place diff-drive-rotation package is losing orientation

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, hardware-interface

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear Ros Community,

I implemented diff-drive-controller package for my custom robot. I tested the generated odometry information while moving back and forward which works perfectly. However, while my robot is turning in place with a zero linear velocity and an angular velocity of 0.21, the generated odometry value moves faster than my robot. For example, when I rotate into 45 degree, my robot model rotates into 90 degree. I believe it is about slippage and there should be a slippage coefficient but I couldn't find something like that in the documentations. How does diff drive controller deals with in place rotations? What should I do for my robot?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/357954/while-rotating-in-place-diff-drive-rotation-package-is-losing-orientation/) by [wallybeam](https://answers.ros.org/users/46586/wallybeam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 57 on 2020-07-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It seems there isn't a slippage value. My problem solved when I change the wheel_seperate distance. It was smaller than the real value. Thank you for this amazing package.

---

Originally posted by [wallybeam](https://answers.ros.org/users/46586/wallybeam/) with karma: 57 on 2020-07-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0